# Github Revert. Unsure about history

Tags: git, github

The project I'm working on has 2 main branches, develop and master. I had set up a pull request for my feature branch but by mistake forgot to choose develop as the base, and so the PR was for master as its default (going to change that).

The PR was actually merged into master as the assigned person either didn't realise or thought it was right. Then my branch was deleted and the PR closed.

A little while later I had realised the mistake that it went into the wrong branch. When I looked at the original PR I noticed a revert button. So after some reading and speaking to another person we did the revert which makes one new commit and a new PR undoing all the commits made by the original PR.

That was then merged in and everything was back to normal. As before the mistake merge.

I restored my original feature branch and made a new PR for develop as originally intended. However just out of curiosity I choose master to see what Github says. Github said that I could not compare or merge as master contains all the commits as my feature branch.

So my question is. When the time is right, how would I get my changes into master if i wanted to merge directly in next week or so?

Or, this is what I'm confused about more, when my feature goes into develop as intended, what is going to happen / how is it going to work when the time comes to merge develop into master?

Remember, master has all the commits of the feature branch followed straight after with a single commit from a temp branch which reversed all the previous merges changes.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it here's the situation you have right now:

1. `feature-branch` has been merged into `master`.
2. `feature-branch` has been merged into `develop`.
3. A pull request that has a commit that reverts the `feature-branch` merge has been merged into `master`.

To get the `feature-branch` changes back in `master` create a new branch and create a commit to revert the revert commit in #3.  Merge this new branch into `master` via pull request.

This end result is that you'll have two pull requests merged into `master` that didn't go through `develop`.  I don't know if that's a deal-breaker but it's straightforward.

See this [article](http://www.tildedave.com/2012/11/24/reverting-a-github-pull-request.html).