# GitHub: Reverted a bad merge to master, but merged files are still present

Tags: git, github, merge, revert, git-reset

In GitHub, I accidentally merged the wrong branch into master. (probably from 
a slip of the finger when selecting from the dropdown) The merge was completed and pushed before I realized my error.

I've looked at:

[Reverting a bad git merge from GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30315263/reverting-a-bad-git-merge-from-github)

[Github: Changes ignored after revert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35407770/github-changes-ignored-after-revert)

[GitHub revert or reset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44799555/github-revert-or-reset)

[Reverting a git merge commit, then reverting the revert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969344/reverting-a-git-merge-commit-then-reverting-the-revert)

[Github Revert. Unsure about history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26191465/github-revert-unsure-about-history)

But none of them successfully addressed the issue, and unless I'm misunderstanding something, they all indicate that the revert should have undone the bad merge, leaving me ready to re-merge the proper branch later on.

My structure is like this:

`/master`

`/dev_2.0`

`/test_2.0`

`/dev_3.0`

`/test_3.0`

All branches are branched off of `/master`. Each test release, `dev_x.0` is pushed to `test_x.0` and at each final prod release, `test_x.0` is merged to `master`.

We have a tag (call it `test_tag_2.0`) on the `test_2.0` branch which reflects the `test_2.0` branch at deployment time. Version 2.0 has gone to production and is completed, 3.0 has development ongoing.

`/master`, for us, is used exclusively for deployed code, and is not touched by anyone but me. No danger of subsequent commits exists in master. No further development is ongoing in `test_2.0`.

What I wanted to do is to roll back the bad merge (`test_3.0` -> `master`) to the state it held prior to the merge, and perform a correct merge (`test_2.0` -> `master`)

Per the advice on several topics on Stack Overflow, I performed a reset on my local repo to undo the bad commit, and pushed it to remote. In GitHub, it shows a successful revert in history. gitk shows the revert as well.

Here's the command I did:

```
`git reset --hard HEAD@{1}`
```

Then pushed to remote

However, now when I compare master to the incorrect source branch `test_3.0`, it shows that master is current with all changes on that branch. Shouldn't the revert have undone that?

It also still shows that master is current with the correct branch `test_2.0`, after the revert I performed. Shouldn't it also show that this is not the case?

So the end result I want is for the `master` branch to be completely identical in all ways to the way it was prior to the bad merge, and for a fresh merge from the correct `test_2.0` branch to `master` to be successful.

Comment: So I tried recreating this in a sandbox project, so I could experiment, and what happens there is that I can perform the reset, but I can't push the reset to GitHub because the reset local master branch no longer shows all the changes that exist in remote master branch. So that completely defeats the purpose of the reset. I'm TRYING to get rid of the newer items in remote master, not ensure they're preserved.

Comment: you need to force-push in a situation like this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509543/how-do-i-properly-force-a-git-push